# Find a equation of a normal vector from point A to the plane

Tags: vectors

I'm having trouble with following problem:

"Find equation of normal vector from point $A(2,3,-1)$ that is normal to the plane $\pi:2x+y-4z+5=0$"

It doesn't seem that tough but I can't seem to work it out. Like, I know I can get a normal vector out of a plane by using plane's equation, but how can I like move that normal vector until point A is right above (or below it) and then turn that into that equation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm $(2,1,-4)$ is given by the plane equation $2x+y-4z+5=0$. To compute the length of the vector, you need to find the point of perpendicualrity, and this can be solved by parameterizing the line passing through $A$ and normal to the plane:
$$
(x,y,z)=(2,3,-1)+\lambda(2,1,-4)
$$
You will solve $\lambda$ by plug the point back in the plane equation:
$$
2(2+2\lambda)+(3+\lambda)-4(-1-4\lambda)+5=0
$$
So $\lambda=-16/21$ and the point of perpendicularity is given by $(10/21,47/21,43/21)$.

Comment: First off, THANK YOU! Second, I did calculations, and I'm just wondering one thing.. That point of perpendicularity is a point where normal from A hits the plane? Like, that's the point on the plane? If so, all I need to do is like create vector out of the point we just got and the A point itself and write off the equation of that line, right? Thank again :)

Comment: @eXtreme dont know what you want, but if what you want is line that is normal to the plane, you could just write from the parameterized equation: $\displaystyle\frac{x-2}{2}=\frac{y-3}{1}=\frac{z+1}{-4}$, i.e. two linear equations, or intersection line of two planes.

Comment: No, you were right and what you wrote helped me.. What I needed to do is find normal vector from point A to that plane, you helped me find the point that normal vector hit the plane on, let's call it P=(10/21...).. Then I just calculate vector AP=(..,...,..) and with a point A I can turn that normal vector into a line and write off its equation.. I hope you see what I'm talking about, but nevertheless you helped me :)